# Can Dash from Fate Reforged be used at instant speed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Fate Reforged is [introducing a new mechanic](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-fate-reforged-2014-12-29#anchor4) called dash. It's reminder text is as follows:

> You may cast this spell for its dash cost. If you do, it gains haste,
>   and it's returned from the battlefield to its owner's hand at the
>   beginning of the next end step.

My question is...  can dash be played at flash (instant) speed?

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to play dash spells at instant speed. In general, if you're playing a creature, giving it haste, and it leaves the battlefield at the end of the turn, it's because you want to attack with it. In that case you're just going to play it during your first main phase anyway. Plus, there's nothing in the text you quoted that indicates that you can cast those spells at instant speed.

Comment: does it say "flash" or "instant"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official rules are not out yet, but my guess is no. The templating on the reminder text strongly suggests that "Dash" will function as an alternative cost that does not affect when you can cast a spell. In this regard, it would be similar to the "Evoke" mechanic.

For creatures with flash, you would be able to "Dash" at instant-speed (similar to [Briarhorn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Briarhorn))

Comment: Fully agree. *Dash* isn't an activated ability that causes you to cast the creature; it's a static ability that functions in any zone from which you can cast the card (to modify casting). Like with *Flashback*, it doesn't allow you to cast the creature when you otherwise couldn't.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Mechanics of Fate Reforged](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-fate-reforged-2014-12-29#anchor4)

> Dash doesn't change when you can cast creature spells—usually only during your main phase.

This means that if the creature has flash you can cast it at instant speed, but otherwise you can only do it during your main phase.